# Webpack + react-native-web: Error: Can't resolve 'BoundingDimensions'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, react-navigation, react-native-web

Here is an issue I cannot figure out :)

I am building a multi platform native+web app, everything was fine. But at some point I had to add react-navigation v3, that is supposed to be web-compatible.

For some reasons some react-native `require` fail:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/Touchable/Touchable.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'BoundingDimensions' in 'C:\Users\root\Desktop\Dev\GG\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable'
 @ ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/Touchable/Touchable.js 1:338-367
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/GestureHandler.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-navigation-stack/dist/views/StackView/StackViewLayout.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-navigation-stack/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js
 @ ./src/navigator/AppsNavigator.tsx
 @ ./src/App.tsx
 @ ./index.web.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3001 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./index.web.ts
```

**So `BoundingDimensions` and `Touchable` are in the same directory, but the `const BoundingDimensions = require('BoundingDimensions');` that is in react-native package fails. Why ?**

Note that I also now encounter some warnings:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/React/cjs/react.development.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\root\Desktop\Dev\GG\node_modules\React\cjs\react.development.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\root\Desktop\Dev\GG\node_modules\React\index.js
* C:\Users\root\Desktop\Dev\GG\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\root\Desktop\Dev\GG\node_modules\react\index.js
 @ ./node_modules/React/cjs/react.development.js
 @ ./node_modules/React/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/Touchable/Touchable.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/GestureHandler.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-navigation-stack/dist/views/StackView/StackViewLayout.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-navigation-stack/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js
 @ ./src/navigator/AppsNavigator.tsx
 @ ./src/App.tsx
 @ ./index.web.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3001 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./index.web.ts
```

Context:

```
React + React-native-web + webpack project
```

Packages

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@clarketm/saga-monitor": "^1.0.8",
    "@types/react": "^16.7.18",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/uuid": "^3.4.4",
    "formik": "^1.4.1",
    "lodash.throttle": "^4.1.1",
    "native-base": "^2.8.0",
    "react": "16.7.0",
    "react-art": "16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "16.7.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
    "react-native-crypto": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-formik": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.12",
    "react-native-randombytes": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.9.13",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.2",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "vm": "^0.1.0",
    "yup": "^0.26.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.9.13",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.7.0",
    "rn-nodeify": "^10.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2",
    "webpack": "^4.28.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  }
```

```

Webpack

```
    const path = require('path');
    const webpack = require('webpack');

```
const appDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../');
const modulesDirectory = path.resolve(appDirectory, 'node_modules');

const babelLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx|ts)$/,

  include: [
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'src'),

    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, 'react-native-uncompiled'),

    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "native-base-shoutem-theme"),
    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "react-navigation"),
    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "react-native-easy-grid"),
    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "react-native-drawer"),
    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "react-native-safe-area-view"),
    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "react-native-vector-icons"),
    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view"),
    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "react-native-web"),
    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "react-native-tab-view"),
    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "static-container"),
    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "@clarketm", "saga-monitor"),
    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "normalize-css-color"),

    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "react-navigation-stack"),
    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "react-native-gesture-handler"),
    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "react-native"),
    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "react-navigation-drawer"),
    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "@react-navigation"),

    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "@bam.tech", "react-native-root-siblings"),
    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "@bam.tech", "react-native-modalbox"),

    path.resolve(modulesDirectory, "react-router-dom"),

  ],
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
      plugins: ['react-native-web', "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"],

    }
  }
};

// This is needed for webpack to import static images in JavaScript files.
const imageLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]'
    }
  }
};



const cssConfiguration = {
  include: [
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web', 'public'),
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'dist'),
  ],
  test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
  loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
};

const fontConfiguration = {
  test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]',
      outputPath: './fonts/'
    }
  }]
};

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  stats: "verbose",
  entry: [
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'index.web.ts'),
  ],

  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web', 'public'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },

  module: {

    rules: [
      babelLoaderConfiguration,
      imageLoaderConfiguration,
      cssConfiguration,
      fontConfiguration,
      {
        // Many react-native libraries do not compile their ES6 JS.
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: /node_modules\/react-native-/,
        // react-native-web is already compiled.
        exclude: /node_modules\/react-native-web\//,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true
        },
      },
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    // This will only alias the exact import "react-native"
    alias: {
      // RN Web
      'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
      // For NativeBase (http://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html)
      "react-native/Libraries/Renderer/shims/ReactNativePropRegistry": "react-native-web/dist/modules/ReactNativePropRegistry",
    },
    // If you're working on a multi-platform React Native app, web-specific
    // module implementations should be written in files using the extension
    // `.web.js`.
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.web.ts', '.web.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],

  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "../public"),
    compress: false,
    port: 9000,
    //host: "0.0.0.0"
  }
}
```